Compose AnimatedContent and custom layout placement conflict causing UI stuttering
Hi I'm having animation issues when using a custom layout with .placeRelative and AnimatedContent. Basically, whenever the Ui transitions from State1 to State2, the Ui's height changes. But the Ui jumps between the the custom layout's (0,0) position and the the AnimatedContent's transitioning position. Such that the UI gets set at the final height's (0,0) position and then immediately gets shown at the (0,0) position of the interim height (causing the stutter) due to the AnimatedContent and SizeTransform. I need to use a custom layout to get the height of the customUi as the underlying UI cannot be measured via IntrinsicHeight as well as prevent the underlying UI from going beyond a certain height requirement, and also need to keep AnimatedContent for transitioning to other states. I'm wondering what can I do to tackle this issue? The problem does go away if I remove AnimatedContent, but need to keep it as the issue only presents for one of the targetStates. I attached some sample code below, I'd appreciate any assistance, thank you!
@Composable
fun compose(uiModel UiModel, modifier Modifier) {
  Surface() {
    AnimatedContent(
      targetState = uiModel.state,
        transitionSpec = {
          fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(100)) togetherWith
          fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(100)) using
              SizeTransform(sizeAnimationSpec = { _, _ -> tween(100) })
          },
        ) { 
          when (targetState) {
            State1 -> {
              ComposeState1(uiModel, modifier)
            }
            State2 -> {
              ComposeState2(uiModel, modifier)
            }
          }
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeState1(uiModel UiModel, modifier Modifier) {
    Row(Modifier.height(50.dp) {
      ...
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeState2(uiModel UiModel, modifier Modifier) {
  var customUiHeight by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

  val customUiLayout =
    @Composable {
      Layout(
        modifier = Modifier,
        content = {
          Column() {
            ... 
          }
        },
      ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val customUi =
          measurables[0].measure(
            constraints.copy(maxHeight = height)
          )
        customUiHeight = customUi.height
        layout(customUi.width, customUi.height) { customUi.placeRelative(0, 0) }
      }
    }

    Row(Modifier.height(customUiHeight)) {
      customUiLayout()
    }
}

